# if link is clicked on one page unhide/show a div on the other page?

Tags: javascript, hyperlink

i have a list of users on the home page (home.php) on my site, i am trying to figure out a way that i can unhide/show a div on their profile page (profile.php) when the user clicks another users profile link from the homepage, so this div on their profile page is only shown after they click on the link from the homepage and otherwise stays hidden.

is this possible to do, and can someone please show me how i might do this:

this code works if i click the link and the div is on the same page as the link but it doesnt work if i click the link on the homepage and the div is on the profile page which is what i want.

home.php

```
<a id="myLink" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:myLinkButtonClick();">click here</a>

<script>
function myLinkButtonClick()
{
    var $element = $('.nswp-frame2');
    if($element.is(':visible')){
        $element.hide();
    } else {
        $element.show();
    }
}


</script>
```

profile.php

```
<hidden div>
```

Comment: You'll need a persistent storage to keep track of stuff across pages, like cookies, local storage or a DB.

Answer (score 0):

In order to accomplish this, you will need to pass some concept of the close state to the secondary page. That could be done in a lot of ways. The simplest (and most prone to problems) would be to pass it as part of the querystring when the user is moving between pages.

A better option would be to employ cookies or a session variable. Backing this with a database  table is an option, but might be overkill (depending on if you need this preference to persist across multiple visits/sessions).

Also, if you are wanting pages that are already open (in another browser tab, for instance), then you will need to implement some kind of Javascript (possibly AJAX) polling solution to periodically update the visibility based on the state of the database/cookie/session variable.